# Call a c program from C++ and pass arguments

Tags: c++, c, execvp

I have a c++ program, and at some point in my program I need to call a c program and pass some arguments to it.

I am working in linux env.

the file simpsh is a compiled c file in the same dir.
resulting_simpsh_command is a string with data of this type
--creat --trunc --wronly f1 and so far.

When I check the values that I recieve in C program, it shows this instead

```
void execute_simpsh(string resulting_simpsh_command)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid == -1)
        perror("Fork failed!");
    else if(pid ==0)
    {
        char* args[256];

        string simpsh ="./simpsh";
        args [0] = (char*) simpsh.c_str();
        string temp_option_holder="";

        int nextCommand=1;

        for(int i=0;i<resulting_simpsh_command.length();i++)
        {
            if(resulting_simpsh_command[i] !=' ')
            {
                temp_option_holder += resulting_simpsh_command[i];
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"saving to argument: "<<temp_option_holder<<endl;
                args [nextCommand] = (char*) temp_option_holder.c_str();
                temp_option_holder="";
                nextCommand +=1;
            }

        }


        cout<<"command numbers "<<nextCommand<<endl;
        args [nextCommand + 1] = NULL;

        if(execvp(args[0],args) == -1)
            cout<<"Failed to open simpsh, maybe you didnt compile?"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        //not important for now

    }
}
```

Comment: Make sense, any advice on how to avoid this issue ?

Comment: Nevermind, my original implementation works for some reason. Not sure why but without changing the code mentioned above, I am getting the right arguments in c program,

Comment: @Saik: For this time: maybe. But what happens after you restart the program or even the computer - UB is UB.

Comment: @Saik I converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the `args` array will be invalid pointers due to your (mis)use of `c_str`.
The pointer becomes invalid as soon as the string's buffer is reallocated.
Some of the `args` pointers could also point to the same thing even though they're valid.

Two options for fixing this (off the top of my head):

Dynamic allocation:

```
args[nextCommand] = strdup(temp_option_holder.c_str());
```

which requires deallocation later.

Or, if you can live with limiting the argument length, you can use another array and avoid the memory management (but then you need to worry about overflows instead):

```
char arg_strings[256][ARGUMENT_LENGTH] = {0};
char* args[256] = {0};

// ...
assert(temp_option_holder.length() < ARGUMENT_LENGTH);
strncpy(arg_strings[nextCommand], temp_option_holder.c_str(), ARGUMENT_LENGTH);
args[nextCommand] = arg_strings[nextCommand];
```

Comment: `strdup()` is not a standard function, and really should not be part of *any* C++ program. Neither should naked pointers indicating ownership...

Comment: @DevSolar `strdup()` is standard POSIX and since OP is already using `fork()` and friends, using `strdup()` isn't a problem either.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has so many nice things beyond `std::cout`. Use them!

The core of this solution is `std::replace()`ing the spaces in your command line with zero bytes, then taking pointers to the beginning of each (C) string in the command line (conveniently using the zero bytes from the `replace()` as terminators), pushing those pointers into a vector we will then pass to `execve()`.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

// Usually I would recommend using const std::string &
// to avoid the copy, but we are going to do violence
// on the argument so we really *want* a writeable copy.
void execute_simpsh( string cmd )
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if ( pid == -1 )
    {
        perror("Fork failed!");
    }
    else if ( pid == 0 )
    {
        // This will hold our pointers -- and is not limited
        // to a maximum amount other than available RAM
        std::vector< char * > args( { "./simpsh" } );

        if ( ! cmd.empty() )
        {
            // Tokenize -- std::string may contain null chars!
            std::replace( cmd.begin(), cmd.end(), ' ', '\0' );

            // std::string is zero-terminated in memory, but that
            // zero char is not considered by .find() so we add one,
            // making the loop below easier.
            cmd.append( '\0' );

            size_t i = 0;

            // Gather pointers to each argument. find_first_not_of()
            // skips leading (and embedded) ex-spaces.
            while ( ( i = cmd.find_first_not_of( '\0', i ) ) != std::string::npos )
            {
                args.push_back( cmd.data() + i );
                // find() skips to the end of the current argument.
                i = cmd.find( '\0', i );
            }
        }

        std::cout << "Tokens: " << args.size() << "\n";

        // args.data() is std::vector's underlying array
        // of the pointers we pushed. How convenient...
        for ( auto token : args.data() )
        {
            std::cout << "  " << token << "\n";
        }

        // ...as "array of char *" is exactly what we need.
        if ( execvp( args[0], args.data() ) == -1 )
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to open simpsh" << std::endl;
        }

        std::exit( 1 );
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that this solution will mercilessly clobber *any* spaces in your command line, including those in quotation marks, and does *not* handle newlines, tabs etc. -- then again, your original solution did not behave differently either, so I will leave extending the capabilities to you.